# CGI site , moscow ml problem

Tags: cgi, ml

i'm using Moscow ML combined with CGI. I have a site that calculates simple arithmetics. When the submit button i pushed, the site is redirected to the actual CGI file that outputs the result of the calculation. Although in my case, it outputs the html code in raw form rather then actually outputting the result in html. Anybody that knows a solution to this problem ? // thx beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing a content-type http header such as:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```